# In a function, one data frame assignments weirdly overwrite another data frame too. (Pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a function where I input a data frame, which serves as a structure.
I create two local data frames equal to that data frame and then I enter different values in the two different data frames, but at the end of the functions, they are the same.
Is it a problem with how Python assignments work?

Before, I called the function in two separate moments outputting the two dataframes separately, with some differences, and it worked fine. Now there seems to be a problem with how assignments and memory work in Python, so I don't know how to make it work. I have only put here the code part where I think the problem takes place.

```
def GeneraTabellaCovarianze(Fisso,Var):
    Gen=Fisso
    Gen1=Fisso

                        if Var=="DifAtt":
                            Pow1=Gen['ForzaDif'][a]*Gen['Dif'][a]/Gen['ForzaOff'][b]*Gen['Att'][b]
                            #print(Gen['Squadra'][a],Pow1)
                            Pow2=Gen['ForzaOff'][a]*Gen['Att'][a]/Gen['ForzaDif'][b]*Gen['Dif'][b]
                            #print(Gen['Squadra'][a],Pow2)
                            print(a,b,count)
                            Gen.at[a,count]=Pow1 #difensivo
                            Gen.at[b,count]=(1/Pow2) #difensivo

                            Gen1.at[a,count]=Pow2 #offensivo
                            Gen1.at[b,count]=(1/Pow1) #offensivo                          
            count=count+1

Gen=Gen.drop(['Squadra','Forza', 'Gen','Att','Dif','ForzaOff','ForzaDif','CostoPor'], axis=1)
Gen1=Gen1.drop(['Squadra','Forza', 'Gen','Att','Dif','ForzaOff','ForzaDif','CostoPor'], axis=1)
return(Gen,Cov,Gen1,Cov1)

(Dif,CovDif,Att,CovAtt)=GeneraTabellaCovarianze(Sq,'DifAtt')
```

I expect the two dataframes to be different, but they always are the same.
Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: When you define gen and gen1 you are making a "shallow" copy. The two copies reference the same memory space. Try making a deep copy. Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gen and Gen1 refer to the same data. Changing one is visible by the other. You should call `copy()` in `Gen1=Fisso.copy()` so that they become independent:

```py
def GeneraTabellaCovarianze(Fisso,Var):
    Gen=Fisso
    Gen1=Fisso.copy()

                        if Var=="DifAtt":
                            Pow1=Gen['ForzaDif'][a]*Gen['Dif'][a]/Gen['ForzaOff'][b]*Gen['Att'][b]
                            #print(Gen['Squadra'][a],Pow1)
                            Pow2=Gen['ForzaOff'][a]*Gen['Att'][a]/Gen['ForzaDif'][b]*Gen['Dif'][b]
                            #print(Gen['Squadra'][a],Pow2)
                            print(a,b,count)
                            Gen.at[a,count]=Pow1 #difensivo
                            Gen.at[b,count]=(1/Pow2) #difensivo

                            Gen1.at[a,count]=Pow2 #offensivo
                            Gen1.at[b,count]=(1/Pow1) #offensivo                          
            count=count+1

Gen=Gen.drop(['Squadra','Forza', 'Gen','Att','Dif','ForzaOff','ForzaDif','CostoPor'], axis=1)
Gen1=Gen1.drop(['Squadra','Forza', 'Gen','Att','Dif','ForzaOff','ForzaDif','CostoPor'], axis=1)
return(Gen,Cov,Gen1,Cov1)

(Dif,CovDif,Att,CovAtt)=GeneraTabellaCovarianze(Sq,'DifAtt')
```

Comment: Thank you, my bad